# how to building ant scripts which would bypass apex scheduled jobs

Tags: deployment, ant

We are in the process of building ant scripts for our deployments. We have scheduled apex jobs which run every 3 minutes to process some functions and currently our deploy targets are failing because it is complaining of schedulable class has jobs running. We cannot stop these jobs to facilitate the deployment. What is the solution to get around this? Anybody has any thoughts on this
Thanks
Buyan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Dan Appleman's](http://danappleman.com/) sessions at DF13 outlines a solution to that problem - you can view the session [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZqqiIg_mynY&list=WLd7885BA9SPh_7fO3oRUbBsrENZo7j3dJ)

Basically, you use the type for interface to avoid the class you are invoking from the scheduled class from being serialized...

Comment: Thanks British Boy. You saved my day. Credit goes to Dan Appleman!!!